# we can t log you in because of an authentication error: No_Oauth_Token: Acess token was not returned

Tags: salesforce, azure-ad-b2c

We have created a Azure ad b2c tenant and registered application and given registered application id in the salesforce.

When we have contacted microsoft, they are telling issue with sales force. Please help me how I can solve this issue. This is high priority for me. Any help would me much appreciated.
error image:

[image: im]

Comment: Have your referred to this dcoument? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_azure.htm&type=5  Have you updated your Azure Application with the Salesforce Callback URL?

Comment: Thanks for helping me Tony! yes i have read that document already. I created a enterprise application in azure ad b2c and registered this created application in the sales force auth providers. Yes i have updated the azure applciation with the salesforce call back url.

Comment: any help on this??

Comment: This wont work since B2C doesnt have user info endpoint. So once you get around this error youll hit a brick wall. You are better off using SAML - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers